# How to combine multiple terms in Gurobi addMConstr?

Tags: python, numpy, gurobi

I am trying to create a matrix constraint with the following terms:

```
sp1 = gp.Model('subproblem1')
I6 = np.identity(6)
y = sp1.addMVar(4,vtype=gp.GRB.CONTINUOUS,name='y') 
vp = sp1.addMVar(6,vtype=gp.GRB.CONTINUOUS,name='vp')
vm = sp1.addMVar(6,vtype=gp.GRB.CONTINUOUS,name='vm')
W = a 6x4 np array
rhs = a 6x1 np array
sp1.addConstr(W@y + I6@vp + I6@vm == rhs)
```

I get the following error:
GurobiError: Incompatible vector dimensions

What is the issue? Best I can tell all terms should equal a [6x1] array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `rhs` has shape `(6,1)` Gurobi thinks it's a matrix, not a vector. You should make sure it has shape `(6,)`:

```py
sp1.addConstr(W@y + I6@vp + I6@vm == rhs.flatten())
```

Comment: That works! I also had success with: sp1.addConstrs(W[i] @ y + I6[i] @ vp - I6[i] @ vm == rhs[i] for i in range(6))